# How do I make sure socket.id is the same on the server and the client after a page reload?

Tags: node.js, redis, socket.io

I am writing a Proof Of Concept (for at least 2 months now) that uses Node cluster (workers), Redis and socket.io.

Socket.io is not in use for chat in this instance - just back to front communication.  Ajax is not an option.

I am using pub/sub for redis and have that piece working (I think).  At least the values returned from pubClient.get('key') are correct.

When I make a request from the front end and do not navigate or reload the page in any way, things work perfectly - I can make 10 requests and 10 responses are received.

Conversely, when I navigate, the same is not true - and I need to deliver the results no matter how much someone navigates on the front end.

It seems there is a disconnect after a reload.  In both consoles -  Dev Tools and node js, the socket ids are the same.  I'm really scratching my head on this one!

Any help out there?

So, for some mainly socket.io code:

**CLIENT:**

```
    socket = io('https://' + location.hostname + ':4444/', {
        transports: ['websocket', 'polling'],
        secure: true,
    });

    socket.on('download', function(data){// after reload, this never hits
        console.log('DOWNLOAD    '+ data.download);
    });

    var pkgs = ['y14Vfk617n6j', 'My77gWYmBLxT', 'IYd6dL9UoXkx'];
    if(pkgs.length > 0){
        for(var i = 0; i < pkgs.length; i++){
            socket.emit('get-request', pkgs[i]);
        }
    }
```

**SERVER:**

```
    var cluster = require('cluster');
    var express = require('express');
    var numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;
    const { setupMaster, setupWorker } = require("@socket.io/sticky");
    const { createAdapter, setupPrimary } = require("@socket.io/cluster-adapter");
    var app = express();
    const https             = require('https');
    const { Server }        = require("socket.io");
    const Redis             = require("ioredis");
    const sock_nodes = [
        {port: 6379, host: '192.168.0.41'},
        {port: 6380, host: '192.168.0.34'},
        {port: 6381, host: '192.168.0.35'},
        {port: 6379, host: '192.168.0.34'},
        {port: 6380, host: '192.168.0.35'},
        {port: 6381, host: '192.168.0.41'}
    ];
    
    const port = 4444;
    const httpServer = https.createServer(options, app);
    const io = new Server(httpServer, {maxHttpBufferSize: 10240000});

    const pubClient = new Redis.Cluster(sock_nodes, {
        redisOptions: {
            password: 'my secret!'
        }
    });
    
    const subClient = pubClient.duplicate(); // I am not actually using this - should I be?

if (cluster.isMaster) {
    for (var i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
        // Create a worker
        cluster.fork();
    }
    cluster.on("exit", (worker) => {
        console.log(`Worker PID ${worker.process.pid} died`);
        var w = cluster.fork();
        console.log('WORKER %d died (%s). restarting...', worker.process.pid, worker.state);
        w.on('message', function(msg){
            console.log("Message Received : " , msg);
        });
    });



} else {

    app.use((req, res, next) => {
        var reqip = req.headers['x-real-ip'] || req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || req.connection.remoteAddress;
        //~ console.log(reqip, md5(reqip));

        var sess = parseCookies(req, 'session_state');
        if(!sess){
            res.cookie('session_state', md5(reqip));
        }
        next();
    });

    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
        getSession(req, res, function(sess){
          getPub('currSockets', sess, function(err, socket){
            res.render("pages/shared/index", {'ns': sess, 'socket': socket});
            });
          });
      });
    });

    app.get('/start', function(req, res){
        getSession(req, res, function(sess){
          getPub('currSockets', sess, function(err, socket){
            res.render("pages/shared/start", {'ns': sess, 'socket': socket});
          });
        });       
    });

    io.on('connection', function (socket) {
        var currUser = parseCookies(socket.request, 'session_state');
        socket.join(currUser);
        
        getPub('currSockets', currUser, function(err, currSockets){
            if (currSockets) {
                currSockets = JSON.parse(currSockets);            
                if (currSockets[currUser]) {
                    if (currSockets[currUser].stream) {                      
                        currSockets[currUser].sock = socket.id;
                        setCurrSockets(currSockets, currUser, null, function(cSocks){
                            
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        
        socket.on('get-request', function(data){ // can be one or many requests
        // there is a similar, currently irrelevant, socket.on('new-request') that is left out here           
            if(data){
                getPub('currSockets', currUser, function(err, currSockets){
                    currSockets = JSON.parse(currSockets);
                    if(currSockets){
                        if(currUser){
                            if(currSockets[currUser]){
                                if(currSockets[currUser].stream){
                                    var str = Object.keys(currSockets[currUser].stream);
                                    for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
                                        if(str[i] !== 'sock'){
                                            if(!currSockets[currUser].stream[str[i]]){
                                                delete currSockets[currUser].stream[str[i]];
                                                setCurrSockets(currSockets, currUser, null, function(cSocks){                         
                                                    checkCurrSockets(currUser, data, socket);           
                                                });
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });

    httpServer.listen(port, () => {
        logs(__line__, `Worker ${process.pid} listening on ${port}`);
    });
}
    function existsPub(key, cb){
        return pubClient.exists(key, cb);
    }

    function setPub(key, val, cb){
        if(val === JSON.stringify({})){
            return pubClient.get(key, cb);
        }
        return pubClient.set(key, val, cb);
    }

    function getPub(key, currUser, cb){
        existsPub(key, function(err, reply){
            if(reply === 1){
                return pubClient.get(key, cb);// always getting an old socket.id
            }
        });
    }

// Here is the piece that doesn't work after reloading the page

    function ioEmit (currSock, target, payload) {
        io.to(currSock).emit(target, payload);  // doesn't work after page reload
    }
// end piece where after reload does not work


    getPub('currSockets', currUser, function(err, currSockets){
        if( currSockets){
            currSockets = JSON.parse(currSockets);
            ioEmit(currUser, 'download', {'download': currSockets[currUser].stream[data]);
        }
    });

    function parseCookies (req, name) {
        var list = {}, rc;
        rc && rc.split(';').forEach(function( cookie ) {
            var parts = cookie.split('=');
            list[parts.shift().trim()] = decodeURI(parts.join('='));
        });
        return list[name];
    }

function getSession(req, res, callback) {
    var sess = false;
    if(req.headers) {// handle  req
        var reqip = req.headers['x-real-ip'] || req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || req.connection.remoteAddress;
        if(req.headers.cookie){
            sess = req.headers.cookie.split('=')[1].split(';')[0];
        } else {
            res.cookie('session_state', md5(reqip));
        }
        return callback(sess);

    } else if(req.request) {// handle socket
        //~ console.log('req.request.headers.cookie', req.request.headers.cookie.split('=')[1]);
        if(req.request.headers.cookie){
            sess = req.request.headers.cookie.split('=')[1].split(';')[0];
            //~ req.emit('join', sess);
            //~ callback({[sess]: {'sock': req.id}});
            callback(req.id);
        }
    } else {
        return callback(null);
    }
}

function setCurrSockets(currSockets, currUser, data, cb){
    if(Object.keys(currSockets[currUser].stream).length > 0){
        if(data){
            if(ready(currSockets, currUser, data)){
                delete currSockets[currUser].stream[data];// it appears that setCurrSockets is getting called too soon
            }
        }
        setPub('currSockets', JSON.stringify(currSockets), function(err){

        });
        if(typeof cb === 'function'){
            setTimeout(() => {
                getPub('currSockets', currUser, function(err, cSocks){
                    cb(cSocks);// updated callback to return cSocks
                }, 2000);
            });
        }
    } else {
        currSockets[currUser].stream = {};
        setPub('currSockets', JSON.stringify(currSockets), function(err){
            if(err){
 
           } else {
                if(typeof cb === 'function'){
                    cb(currSockets);// updated callback to return cSocks
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot.  When a new page is loaded, the client will request a NEW socket.io connection and that will correctly be assigned a new `socket.id`. If you want to keep track of the same client from one page to the next, you should use a cookie or express-session to do that and you can then attach the new `socket.id` to that session when the client connects on the new page.

Comment: Thanks.  I thought I was using a cookie?  It seems I have left out some necessary code. Updating now - added getSession

Comment: @jfriend00 - added getSession to the code above - I had omitted it for some stupid reason!

Comment: What is this `sess = req.headers.cookie.split('=')[1].split(';')[0];`?  It appears you're trying to access a cookie by position in the split array without ever looking at its name.  That's not good.  FYI, there is pre-made cookie parsing middleware that's fully tested for accessing a specific cookie without manually parsing it yourself.

Comment: well, this is a POC and I am not aware of that middleware, and there is only one cookie but I appreciate your input @jfriend00

Comment: Well, I don't know what you want from us then?  You do not preserve `socket.id` from one socket to the next.  Instead, you make some other cookie that uniquely identifies the client (it should be a randomly assigned id in the cookie, not their IP address because that can change as users move).  Then, you can use the value in that session cookie as a key to session storage where you can store the latest `socket.id` for that user.  And, the cookie middleware and express-session already implement most of the plumbing for you, you just assign/read data to/from the session object.

Comment: Thanks again!  I believe all of your comments will help me tomorrow as I continue my quest to achieve the near (seemingly) impossible!  If my only problem is preserving the socket.id (don't really want to, since it changes with every page load) - or are you saying that is what I AM trying to do and should not?

Comment: I am saying that you should not be trying to retain the value of socket.id.  Instead, when you get an incoming socket.io connection, you get the socket.id for that new connection and you get the cookie for that client and that lets you update your internal (on the server) reference table that says what socket.id this client is using.  I'd really recommend you use [express-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session) and [cookie-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-parser) middleware as they've already written and engineered all the plumbing you need.

Answer (score 0):

figured this out.  The problem was in here:

```
for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
  if(str[i] !== 'sock'){
                                            
    >>>>  if(!currSockets[currUser].stream[str[i]]){  // never true
       // delete currSockets[currUser].stream[str[i]];
       setCurrSockets(currSockets, currUser, null, function(cSocks){                         
                                                    
         checkCurrSockets(currUser, data, socket);           
       });
     }
   }
 }
```

so I commented the for loop and kept the setCurrSockets part and it works.
Just thought I would share, in case someone else tries to use redis, node cluster and socket.io together.  As @jfreind00 said, you should use an authentication system with a randomly gen'd string for storing cookies.

Comment: Thanks again @jfriend00 - your comments led me to the solution!